# SVG side by side - rotate 90 all of them

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have 2 SVG (**horizontal view**):

```
<svg id="svgC1" height="52.215796" width="257.597148" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polyline points="0,6.326886 178.017424,6.326886 178.017424,45.888910 0,45.888910" fill="green"></polyline>
    <polyline points="178.017424,7.892542 257.597148,7.892542 257.597148,44.323254 178.017424,44.323254" fill="blue"></polyline>
</svg>
<svg id="svgC2" height="52.215796" width="257.597148" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polyline points="0,6.326886 178.017424,6.326886 178.017424,45.888910 0,45.888910" fill="blue"></polyline>
    <polyline points="178.017424,7.892542 257.597148,7.892542 257.597148,44.323254 178.017424,44.323254" fill="green"></polyline>
</svg>
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/y85s290r/1/)

I have tried to group the polylines and then apply transform rotate 90, but I am always "losing" the images since the main svg is wide and narrow.

What is the easiest way to rotate them 90 degrees and place them side by side (**vertical view**)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to rotate each picture around a point near the left end, so that they become vertical at the left side of a new object.  So since the SVGs have a height of 252.125, you would chose a roation point of approx 26.17.

The simplest way to do that is add a group element surrounding the polylines and add the transform to that.

```
  <g transform="rotate(90,26.17,26.17)">
    <polyline points="0,6.326886 178.017424,6.326886 178.017424,45.888910 0,45.888910" fill="green"></polyline>
    <polyline points="178.017424,7.892542 257.597148,7.892542 257.597148,44.323254 178.017424,44.323254" fill="blue"></polyline>
  </g>
```

Then turn the SVGs from "landscape" to "portrait" by switching the width and height on each.

```
<svg id="svgC1" width="52.215796" height="257.597148" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="rotate(90,26.17,26.17)">
    <polyline points="0,6.326886 178.017424,6.326886 178.017424,45.888910 0,45.888910" fill="green"></polyline>
    <polyline points="178.017424,7.892542 257.597148,7.892542 257.597148,44.323254 178.017424,44.323254" fill="blue"></polyline>
  </g>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y85s290r/5/

To rotate anti-clockwise, rotate -90 degrees instead.  That will leave the object sitting just off the top of the SVG, so you need to move it down.  To do that just use a `translate()` transform after the rotate.

```
<g transform="translate(0,257.6) rotate(-90)">
```

Note: the translate occurs first in the list because the transform operations are applied right to left.

https://jsfiddle.net/y85s290r/7/

Comment: thanks for the answer, and it is almost the way I wanted but it seems that is the other 90angle :) in your example -90 does not work.

Comment: I updated the answer with a version that rotates in an anticlockwise direction.

Comment: that's it :) thanks for such a fast answer. Have a nice weekend.